# Set proxy for a flatpak app

Tags: proxy, flatpak

Is there a way I can permanently connect the Flatpak app to Tor (that is accessible with `SOCKS5://127.0.0.1:9050`) in my laptop to bypass the government censorship?

Specifically, I want to be able to access WhatsApp (for example `com.ktechpit.whatsie`).

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide which distro/version of distro you are using?

Comment: Two distributions: Ubuntu 22 and Debian 12, but I want to use tor proxy for one them (no difference)